# Direct access to Windows virtual printer port

Tags: windows, printing, usb

There seems to be a method of directly writing and reading data to Windows USB virtual printer port (e.g. USB001) without usage of dedicated printer driver.
Anybody an idea how do do that?

Comment: How about setting up the printer driver as 'generic text' and then sending your output to the queue using "copy file.xyz \\workstation\share".  I might have a better way to handle this, will check at the office tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is what I put in my original comments.  You can create a USB printer using whatever driver you want (gerneric text always works well), then share it out.  From here you can connect to the share using something like

```
net use lpt1 \\your_workstation\printer_share
```

You can then print to lpt1 (or copy to lpt1) and you will leverage the Windows spooler to get the file there.

The other option is to do this in code sending the data directly to the printer you created (without sharing, assuming its installed on the same system).

[How to send raw data to a printer by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)

You could also send data directly to the USB port but that's a lot of work from my perspective to do something that already is nicely packages in the Windows spooler. Not to mention, you get all the upside of the spooler including, pausing and queueing jobs.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your second option, sending raw data to printer spooler in code. But therefore I need to install a printer driver. Sending data directly to USB port would be better for me. I've seen a tool that was able to do that, by just connecting to "USB001", no printer driver installed.

Comment: You can just install the Generic Text driver.  It will act as a pass-through and every Windows box has it.